# Prove that if a series in a Banach space converge absolutely then any reordering does too.

Tags: real-analysis

A reordering of the series $\sum x_n$ in a Banach space X is a series $\sum x_{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi:\mathbb{Z_+}\to \mathbb{Z_+}$ is a bijection.

Therefore I want to prove that if $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely, and converges to $x$, then any reordering of $\sum x_n$ converges to $x$.

My question is Do the proof given in Gaughan's book (4ed. page 197) works in this case?

Proof:

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ and $S_{n}^{1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{\tau (k)}$

Now $\{ S_n\}$ converges to $A$.We seek to prove that  $\{ S_{n}^{1}\}$ also converges to A. Choose $\epsilon >0$.There is $N$ such that for $n \leq N$,

$$|S_n-A|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}|<\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

(since the series $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ converges absolutely).Now, T is a 1-1 function mapping $\{1,2,\ldots \}$ onto $\{1,2,\ldots \}$; hence, there is $K \geq N$ such that $\{1,2,\ldots ,N\} \subset \{T(1),T(2),\ldots ,T(K)\}$.Assume $n \geq K$.Then:

$$|S_{n}^{1}-A| \leq |S_{n}^{1}-S_{n}|+|S_{n}-A|<|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{\tau(k)}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\sum_{k=N+1}^{\inf}|a_{k}|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Comment: What is the proof in Gaughan's book? And what precisely does it prove? I guess it will need only small modifications (if any, except for notation).

Comment: Ok let me post it only be patient please because I am really slow typping :)

Comment: No problem. But if you are slower at typing than I am, you should probably practice a bit more ;)

Comment: Ready :), there is it :)

Comment: You have made a couple of typos in the proof, it must be "for all $n \geqslant N$", not $n \leqslant N$, and it is $$\lvert S_n - A\rvert = \Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty a_k\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ And you switch between $\tau$ and $T$. But with those mistakes fixed, the proof works as is, provided one denotes the norm $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert$. Alternatively, you can replace the absolute value signs with $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$.

Comment: Ok so the proof is the same right? I think it works because R is a banach space right?

Comment: I think is right isnt, because $T$ is a function and $\tau$ the reordering right?

Comment: I am back I am sorry for the delay but I was in a conference, so why the changes?

Comment: Which changes? The typos should be clear, and apart from those one only needs to notice that the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$ is nothing special, the argument works for every norm [such that the space is complete, if we deduce convergence from absolute convergence; if we assume absolute convergence and convergence (for one ordering), the proof doesn't even require completeness].

Comment: Ok, but I am really sure that it has $T$ and $\tau$ I've got the book here :), so what do you recommend?

Comment: Or do you have an email so I can send it to you :)

Comment: Interpret $\tau = T$. It may be a slip-up, or maybe it was intentional (I can't guess what the intention would be, though). Anyway, it's not pertinent to the argument.

Comment: jajajaja wait I've noticed that it is $T$ everywhere :) not $\tau$ jajaja let me check the other ones :)

Comment: Right, I've got typos jajajaj and the correct proof is as you have it, so I only change norm and obviously the limits :) (this is change A by x) :)